# supervisord stopping child processes

Tags: bash, apache-zookeeper, supervisord, ubuntu-11.04

One of the problems, I face with supervisord is that when I have a command which in turn spawns another process, supervisord is not able to kill it.

For example I have a java process which when runs normally is like

```
 $ zkServer.sh start-foreground
 $ ps -eaf | grep zk
 user 30404 28280  0 09:21 pts/2    00:00:00 bash zkServer.sh start-foreground
 user 30413 30404 76 09:21 pts/2    00:00:10 java -Dzookeeper.something..something
```

The supervisord config file looks like:

```
[program:zookeeper]
command=zkServer.sh start-foreground
autorestart=true
stopsignal=KILL
```

These kind of processes which have multiple childs are not well handled by supervisord when it comes to stopping them from `supervisorctl`. So when I run this from the supervisord and try to stop it from supervisorctl, only the top level process gets killed but not the actual java process.

Comment: It is my understanding that the [`systemd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) `init`-replacement's use of [`cgroups`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) allows for reliably tracking child processes. It might be suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 115):

The same problem was encountered by Rick Hanlon II here: https://coderwall.com/p/4tcw7w

Option **stopasgroup=true** should be set in the program section for supervisord to stop not only the parent process but also the child processes.

The example is given as:

```
[program:some_django]
 command=python manage.py runserver
 directory=/dir/to/app
 stopasgroup=true
```

Also, have in mind that you may have an older package of supervisord that does not have "stopasgroup" functionality.
I tried these Debian packages on Raspberry Pi:

- supervisor_3.0a8 does not work.
- supervisor_3.0b2-1 works as expected.

Comment: Also note that supervisord doesn't take configuration changes automatically. You'll need to run `supervisorctl update` to apply changes to your configuration, or restart the supervisord process.

Comment: This should really be the default option.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me with supervisor 3.2. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Doing the following early in the main bash script called by supervisord fixed the problem for me:

```
trap "kill -- -$$" EXIT
```

This kills the entire process group when the main script exits, such as when it is killed by supervisord.

Answer (score 10):

try this supervisor program config:

```
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
stopsignal=INT
```

Comment: Note: stopasgroup=true implies killasgroup=true. no need to mention again. http://supervisord.org/configuration.html

Answer (score 6):

A feature was recently added to supervisord to send SIGKILL to the whole process group.  It's in [github](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/pull/30) but not officially released yet.

If the process id is available in a file, you can use the [pid-proxy program](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#pidproxy-program)

Answer (score 4):

The following article has an in-depth discussion of the problem:

http://veithen.github.io/2014/11/16/sigterm-propagation.html

Comment: exec ... solved it for me. The first option in the article. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for teaching how to catch the fish instead of supplying it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use priorities in `/conf.d/your-configuration.conf` file. For example, if you want to run zookeeper first and then kafka you can specify two programs.

Lower priority means that the program starts first and stops last.