# Does supervisord managed subprocess?

Tags: python, supervisord

I'm using supervisord for managing process.

(To avoid zombie process, and other difficult thing to manage process)

Assume that I will run python script that using multiprocessing.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def fetch():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("I'm still alive...")


def main():
    processes = [
        Process(target=fetch),
        Process(target=fetch),
        Process(target=fetch),
        Process(target=fetch),
        Process(target=fetch),
        Process(target=fetch),
        Process(target=fetch),
        Process(target=fetch),
        [And more process here...]
    ]
    for process in processes:
        process.start()

main()
```

Above code, `fetch()` create many processed and run it.

In this case, if processes that created by `fetch()` become zombie process,

supervisord managing it?(ex. Auto kill and restart)

Or, just managing root process only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supervisord manages the child process, which is responsible for managing anything it spawns. However, if you want to ensure that all the subprocesses are stopped with the main process, use `stopasgroup=true` in the `supervisord.conf` file.

See related question: [supervisord stopping child processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090683/supervisord-stopping-child-processes)

Comment: I tried `stopasgroup=true` and `killasgroup=true` but it doesn't work. Assume that parent process id=1 and child id =2, 3. In this case if I kill process id=1, process_id=2,3 doesn't killed and new process is launched.

Comment: If the above is the extent of your code, the processes ending up zombies is from the multiprocessing handling and not supervisor. See related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477320/python-multiprocessing-kill-processes and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506489/python-multiprocessing-leading-to-many-zombie-processes

Comment: You're right. Child process have to handled by python code.